# Initialize a class object with the this pointer in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, this, this-pointer

In *C++*, I want to initialize (or change) a class object using the result of another class' method. Can I use the *this* pointer? Is there a better way?

Dummy example:

```
class c_A {
    public:
    int a, b;

    void import(void);
};

class c_B {
    public:

    c_A create(void);
};

void c_A::import(void) {
    c_B B; 
    *this = B.create();
};

c_A c_B::create(void) {
    c_A A;
    A.a = A.b = 0;
    return A;
};
```

Comment: This will work but it looks suspicious as hell. I would not let it pass a code review. Why not let the caller call B.create()? (factory)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no problem. The member function `void import(void);` is not a constant function.In this statement

```
*this = B.create();
```

there is used the default copy assignment operator.

> Is there a better way?

A better way is not to use a member function and just use an assignment statement for objects of the class as for example

```
c_A c1 = { 10, 20 };

c1 = c_B().create();
```